Two detectives bouncing a ball off their office wall
It was most definitely a movie, but it MIGHT have been a TV show episode or a pilot. I've seen it on TV sometime in the 90s.
There were two (private?) detectives working together and at some point I think some lady joined them (their secretary maybe?). I think it was a period piece because characters were wearing tweed suits and period dresses that looked like 1940s up to 60s.
The most important detail I remember was the detectives were exchanging the information they've discovered in investigation and theories they had while throwing and catching a ball at their office wall alternately (as in, one throws, the other catches and throws, then the first catches, and so on, basically like playing Squash without paddles). It was like their ritual, because that happened multiple times and I think at one point the aforementioned lady even joined them in it.
It was in color and in English language, but I think more likely from UK than USA.
